# RetryableTopic - Configure different concurrency on retry/dlt topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using **spring-kafka 2.9.12**

I'm currently using the **RetryableTopic** feature, and I wish to set up **different concurrency** for the **main** topic and the **retry/DLT** topics.

I've noticed that in the newer version (3.0.x) of spring-kafka, this is natively supported.
However, in the older versions, is there a way to configure this or a workaround to achieve the same result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With earlier versions, you can set `autoStartup` to false (on the `@KafkaListener`). You can then get a reference to each container (via the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean), cast the container to a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` and change the concurrency; then start the container. It is easier to do this if you give the primary listener an `id`; the retry container names are then based on that.

This technique can also be used if you wish to use a different concurrency for the DLT container Vs. the retry containers.